# Arithmetic Derivative

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

In Calculus, whenever we see a constant and want to take the derivative of it, it always is $0$. However in Number Theory, we have something called the arithmetic derivative in which we can differentiate to get some nonzero term.  So we can denote the arithmetic derivative the same way as in calculus, say for some $x$, we can say $x'$ to be the arithmetic derivative. Some properties of arithmetic derivatives are that:

- For all primes, the arithmetic derivative is $1$.
- Product Rule: $(xy)'=x'y+xy'$
- $0'=1'=0$

Now, there is also some lesser-known sub-part to the arithmetic derivative called the Arithmetic Product Derivative, $P(n)$. In this case, if $$\ n= p_1^{x_1} \cdot p_2^{x_2} \cdot ... \cdot  p_k^{x_k}  ,$$ then  $$ P(n) =  x_1 \cdot p_1^{x_1 - 1} \cdot x_2 \cdot p_2^{x_2 - 1} \cdot ... \cdot  x_k \cdot p_k^{x_k-1} .$$

> Are there are infinitely values of $a$ such that $P(a)=P(a-5)+5$?

Comment: One might want to look at [A003415](https://oeis.org/A003415) - not for the answers, but for the broader perspective.

Comment: Do mention clearly that the product derivative is different from the arithmetic derivative.

Comment: The answer is very likely yes.  If $x$ is square-free, then $P(x) = 1$, and if $y$ is square-free and not divisible by $3$, then $P(9 \cdot y) = 6$.  So we can reduce the problem to: if $y$ is square-free and not divisible by $3$, is $9 \cdot y - 5$ square-free infinitely often?

Comment: There are certainly a few; $a=18, 63, 90, 99$ are the solutions up to 100.

Comment: There seem to be a lot. There are 307 values of $y\le1111$ not divisible by 3 such that $y$ and $9y-5$ are both squarefree. 3074 values up to 11111; 30742 up to 111111; 307254 up to 1111111.